# What tool to make flow graphs in Linux?

Tags: graphics, diagrams, syntax

SQLite documentation is very nice with graphs such as

[image: SQLite documentation image]

Any idea of what software can I use to do similar picture? It would be perfect if the images could be described textually, instead of drawing using graphical interface. I use Linux and I'm looking for free software.

Comment: You could do that in `TikZ`

Comment: You can use PGF/Tikz. You can find examples of how to use it [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/), and the wiki page is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ), a wikibook can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ), and the offical manual (726 pages!) is [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These diagrams are called "[syntax diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram)" or "railroad diagrams". There is a package called **[rail](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rail)** for drawing them.